# Check if one propertie of an object is null or undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an object like this :

```
    $scope.contact = {
        name: contact.gd$name.gd$givenName.$t,
        familyName: contact.gd$name.gd$familyName.$t,
        phone: contact.gd$phoneNumber[0].$t,
        mail: contact.gd$email[0].address,
        organization: contact.gd$organization[0].gd$orgTitle.$t
    };
```

How can I inspect this object in order to check if one of its propertie is null/undefined, and tell me which one ?

I could write a loop, but if there's a faster way, it could be better.

Comment: You have like 5 properties how "fast" this check should be?

Comment: Try my answer hope it will work :)

Comment: Why am I getting -1 ? This is not a correct question ?

Comment: It shows no research effort and not clear. For example why would you need to avoid loop? What makes you think looping is somehow slow? How many times your code runs this check to make it affect overall application performance?

Comment: It is not about speed. This is for code maintainability improvement.
If I want to add some properties in my object, I don't want to add lines in a loop. I want to write a function, like @gurvinder372 wrote, to check all indexes in my obj

Comment: "It is not about speed." but you are asking about "a faster way". How come this is not about performance? What do you mean by "faster"? And can't imagine you didn't discover `for-in` and `Object.keys` after like 10 seconds of googling.

Comment: "Faster way" stands for code writting. Sorry if I didn't use right terms.

Comment: Well, ok. Just out of curiosity. How would you write a loop checking properties to be null that requires one to add lines for new properties?

Comment: That's what I'm searching for ^^

Answer (score 2):

Check it this way

```
var nullProps = Object.keys( $scope.contact ).filter( function( key, index, arr ){ return typeof $scope.contact[ key ] == "undefined";  })
```

This is essentially iterating all the properties of the object `$scope.contact` and returning only those whose value is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: `arr` is an array of properties name `arr[ key ]` almost certainly will be undefined. Correct check should be `$scope.contact[key] == null` because OP asks for "null/undefined"

Comment: @YuryTarabanko you are right, my bad. Missed it somehow ;(

Comment: @gurvinder372 i guess it is returning a boolean. `return typeof true;`

Comment: this solution is still a loop shrouded with an object method.

Comment: @Jai  you mean `nullProps` will be an array of `boolean` values?

Comment: OP has to use a loop no matter what, it's an enumerable task afterall

Comment: @gurvinder372 there could be "boolean" instead of keys.

Comment: @Jai sorry, can you clarify this a bit more :) `"boolean" instead of keys`.Really not getting it, I could be slow though.

Comment: @gurvinder372 what i meant was if conditon `$scope.contact[ key ] == "undefined";` is true then `typeof true` would print `"boolean"` instead of values of array.

Comment: @Jai true, but I need to return the array of `key`s which satisfy this condition `type $scope.contact[ key ] == "undefined"` means only those keys whose values are either `null` or `undefined`. if the value is `true`, then it does not satisfy this condition and its key shouldn't be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper function to filter keys with null/undefined values:

```js
const obj = {
    name: 'Name',
    id: 1000,
    here: null,
    parent: undefined,
    zero: 0,
    bool: false    
}

const emptyKeys = obj => Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key] == null)

const r = emptyKeys(obj);

console.log(r);
```

Comment: `obj[key] == null` that's it. Only `null` and `undefined` equals `null`